# list comprehension to filter a list of lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

This problem is from https://leetcode.com/problems/find-players-with-zero-or-one-losses/. Is it possible to use list comprehension in this problem to create a new list that only has the first item of every tuple that never shows up in the second item of any tuple.

For instance:

`matches = [[1,3],[2,3],[3,6],[5,6],[5,7],[4,5],[4,8],[4,9],[10,4],[10,9]]`

I want a new list of:

`neverLost = [1, 2, 10]`

I would make two lists, one for each part of the question with list comprehension and then concatenate them together afterwards for the solution. I tried using list comprehension but I'm having syntax issues

`neverLost = [w for w, l in matches if w not l]`

The first part **w for w, l in matches** works fine and will create a list of just the first item of each tuple `[1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 4, 4, 4, 10, 10]`, but I'm struggling with the syntax and understanding of the expression to filter the "winners". Please let me know if this is even a good solution for the problem. I know I can probably do this with a dictionary, but I wanted to know if this way was also possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension works, but not optimised way to solve these sort of problems

```
In [48]: list(set([j[0] for j in matches if j[0] not in [i[1] for i in matches]]))
Out[48]: [1, 2, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you did

```
neverLost = [w for w, l in matches if w not l]
```

is going to check whether the first item in that tuple is equal to the second item in that same tuple. It is **not** checking whether the first item is present at 2nd position in any other tuple.

You can use this -

```
list(set([w[0] for w in matches if w[0] not in [l[1] for l in matches]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do something like,

```
matches = [[1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 6], [5, 6], [5, 7], [4, 5], [4, 8], [4, 9], [10, 4], [10, 9]]

losses_dict = {}
for (_, value) in matches:
    losses_dict.setdefault(value, 0)  # key might exist already
    losses_dict[value] += 1

final_list = [
              [k for k, _ in matches if k not in losses_dict.keys()],
              [k for k, v in losses_dict.items() if v == 1]
             ]
```

The dict.setdefault checks if the key already existis otherwise it appends the value 0.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, something like this is a reasonable solution:

```
seconds = {second for _, second in matches}
never_lost = [first for first, _ in matches if first not in seconds]
never_lost = list(dict.fromkeys(never_lost))  # idiom for removing duplicates while maintaining order
```

Now, if you mean *only using a single list comprehension expression*, then you'd have to get pretty janky:

```
never_lost = [
    x for x in
    {
        first: None
        for first, _ in matches 
        for seconds in [{second for _, second in matches}] 
        if first not in seconds
    }
]
```

I'd stick to the first approach. Not everything has to or should be a single list comprehension expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
neverLost = list(set(w for w, l in matches if all(w != j for i, j in matches)))
```

List comprehensions are good for performance but most of the time complex list comprehensions can decrease code readability.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to model the problem as a directed graph where each player is a vertex of the graph and edge determines result of the match, such that edge direction is from winner to loser.

for eg.

> [1, 2] => [1](winner) -> [2](loser)

Now problem boils down to calculating in-degree/out-degree of the vertices, which should give us the desired result.